# share point rest api GetFolderById returns System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365api

I am using share point `rest api` to get files and folders from a share point library. I have two libraries (with `GUID`) and this is the api endpoint that I'm using:

```
/_api/web/GetFolderById('{$guid}')?\$expand=Folders,Files
```

the `api` returns all folders and files as expected for the first library with `guid` of library but the problem is for the second one it returns this error even though I'm using folder endpoint:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-2147024894, System.IO.FileNotFoundException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-EN",
            "value": "File Not Found."
        }
    }
}
```

I also used `getfolderbyserverrelativeurl` endpoint with relative folder paths. this endpoint returns the expected results for the first folder but this error for the second one:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-EN",
            "value": "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I can view the second folder in the web with the same credentials (`username` and `password`).

So here is my question: is there another way to get all files and folders using share point rest `api`? if not what is the mistake in my approaches?

Comment: Could it be, that there is or are multiple files inside the second folder, that you are not permitted to view and that is causing the issue and not the folder itself? What happens, if you only expand folders and not the files?

Comment: @Marco the same result (file not found with GetFolderById and Access denied with getfolderbyserverrelativeurl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route to `api` endpoints for site collections are different from main site. for example if you want to access to folder `A` in site collection `B` you must use this endpoint to get the root folder `GUID`:

```
http://sitename/sites/collection_name/_api/web/lists(guid'7EA06E82-C7C1-41FE-AF8B-C3341E928D6A')/rootFolder
```

and then use this endpoint with root folder `GUID` to get all files and folders:

```
http://sitename/sites/collection_name/_api/web/GetFolderById('26728694-ee8e-4618-a524-5ea6ba545384')?$expand=Folders/ListItemAllFields,Files/ListItemAllFields
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this endpoint to get all subfolders inside the library, then find the folder Unique Id:

/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/rootFolder/Folders?$expand=ListItemAllFields

[image]

Use this unique Id inside GetFolderById like below, works in my side:

/_api/web/GetFolderById('6a7de691-321a-41e9-8927-5594082d5a94')?$expand=Folders,Files

Comment: "List '/regulation' does not exist at site"

Comment: the resources are not lists but libraries

Comment: @MehrdadEP, no problem, Lists/GetByTitle can get both lists and libraries, please make sure the library name is valid in the target site.